# Gitlab packer ami pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, devops, packer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIq5c.png)

Facing this error while I'm trying to run my gitlab ci file

```
$ packer init aws.pkr.hcl
Installed plugin github.com/hashicorp/amazon v1.3.0 in "/root/.config/packer/plugins/github.com/hashicorp/amazon/packer-plugin-amazon_v1.3.0_x5.0_linux_amd64"
$ packer build aws.pkr.hcl
custom-image.amazon-ebs.ubuntu: output will be in this color.
Build 'custom-image.amazon-ebs.ubuntu' errored after 52 seconds 929 milliseconds: error validating regions: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post "https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/": net/http: invalid header field value for "Authorization"
==> Wait completed after 52 seconds 929 milliseconds
==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> custom-image.amazon-ebs.ubuntu: error validating regions: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post "https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/": net/http: invalid header field value for "Authorization"
==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Here is my gitlab ci file

image: amazonlinux

```
stages:
  - build-ami

variables:
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"  
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_CI
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_CI
```

before_script:

- AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
- export AWS_Access_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_CI
- export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_CI
- yum update -y
- yum install sudo -y
- sudo yum update -qy
- sudo yum install -y unzip
- sudo yum update -qy

## # Install AWS CLI

## - curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"

## - unzip awscliv2.zip

## - sudo ./aws/install

## Install Packer

- sudo yum install -y yum-utils
- sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://rpm.releases.hashicorp.com/AmazonLinux/hashicorp.repo
- sudo yum -y install packer

build-ami:
stage: build-ami
script:
- packer init aws.pkr.hcl
- packer build aws.pkr.hcl